# How to search between two dates in SQL using session variables based on another condition

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have an MS Access table and need to filter the records by date and location. I am also working with ASP.NET in C#. I am pulling the beginning date, ending date, and location data from another .aspx page with session variables. The field that holds the date is in Date/Time format but the session variables are a string.
I am using the following SQL statement to sort for what I need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Observation 
WHERE locationID = " + location + " 
(SELECT * 
 FROM Observation 
 WHERE observationDate >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(beginDate) + "' 
 AND observationDate <=  = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(endDate) + "')
ORDER BY observationID";
```

How can I sort between the two dates based on the location that I choose? The location part of the query works  but I cannot get the date segment to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple, you are almost there:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Observation 
WHERE locationID = " + location + " 
AND observationDate >= #" + Convert.ToDateTime(beginDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "# 
AND observationDate <=  = #" + Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "#)
ORDER BY observationID";
```

You only need 1 WHERE in this query. Most important is the date-formatting

The single quotes should be replaced by #

Comment: Thank you, but this throws a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." error. This is what I keep running into.

Comment: Thank you the "#" worked instead of " ' ". What is the difference between the two? Thanks again.